# Serverless does not recognise subdirectories in Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, graphql, serverless

I am running a simple API using serverless and AWS Lambda.

I am unable to run a simple test query locally using serverless invoke local -f graphql -p query.json because I get the following error:

[image]

my apolloServer.js depends on variables and functions from subdirectories to work - it would be too much to put all of the code in apolloServer.js - the folder structure looks like this:

[image]

apolloServer.js depends on imports from the graphql, utils folder etc, but it seems like serverless is unable to import them without throwing an error.

How do you get serverless to recognise imports from subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

I use [serverless-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-webpack) to create the bundle that then runs in the lambda.

At the bottom of my serverless.yml file I have:

```
custom:
  webpack:
    packager: 'npm'
    webpackConfig: 'webpack.config.js' # Name of webpack configuration file
    includeModules:
      forceInclude:
        - pg
```

> I force include pg because my project requires it but your requirements may differ, it's just here for illustration.

A minimal `webpack.config.js` file might include [[docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration/#introductory-configuration)]:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './foo.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'foo.bundle.js',
  },
};
```

where `./foo.js` is your entry point, `./dist` is where you want the bundle to be created, and `foo.bundle.js` is the name of bundle.

Webpack is normally used to bundle js/ts files into a single file for deployment on the web. However it can also be used to do the same thing for a lambda to deploy on a node server.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on this? What would be in webpack.sls.config.js? Are there any further steps to take than just npm i serverless-webpack and putting your settings in serverless.yml ?

Comment: Thanks, I gave a tick for the correct answer but unfortunately Webpack was unable to resolve peer dependencies in my api properly - thus I conclude that using serverless and Lambda with Apollo Server is not worth doing.

Comment: I'm running Apollo as a lambda using serverless and webpack. It works really well.

Comment: I would be interested to know how you managed it - I was unable to get past Module-Not-Found errors, peer dependency conflict errors etc. After one week of trying I gave up. Is there a guide somewhere you would recommend?

Comment: We should discuss in chat.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help: I have made a more in depth explanation of the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74928477/serverless-cannot-run-simple-example-query-using-node-js